Offsetting identical lines in pgfplots
I have the following problem. I have this code that displays plots with error bars. Unfortunately, I have many points in my data in a plot that are the same and then overlap in the plot (see the right side of my plot). How can I better show that it is overlapping? What design options are there?
This is the code:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage\[margin=1in\]{geometry}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\lipsum\[1\]
\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}\[b\]{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}\[
                width=\linewidth,
                height=0.6\linewidth,
                xlabel={\footnotesize $x$},
                ylabel={\footnotesize $y$},
                xmin=0, xmax=0.1,
                ymin=8, ymax=16,
                grid=major,
                title={\footnotesize a)},
                tick label style={font=\scriptsize},
                title style={at={(-0.15,1.15)}, anchor=north west},
                xtick={0,0.02,0.04,0.06,0.08,0.10},
                xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/precision=2},
                legend style={
                    font=\footnotesize,
                    legend columns=-1,
                    cells={anchor=west},
                    draw=black,
                },
                legend to name=commonlegend
            \]
            \addplot\[
                color=red,
                mark=*,
                solid,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            \] 
            coordinates {
                (0.00,8) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.10,9.2) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
            };
            \addlegendentry{Var 1a}
            
            \addplot\[
                color=red,
                mark=square*,
                densely dashed,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            \]
            coordinates {
                (0.00,8) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.10,10.5) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
            };
            \addlegendentry{Var 1b}
            
            \addplot\[
                color=blue,
                mark=*,
                solid,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            \]
            coordinates {
                (0.00,8) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.10,9.2) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
            };
            \addlegendentry{Var 2a}
            
            \addplot\[
                color=blue,
                mark=square*,
                densely dashed,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            \]
            coordinates {
                (0.00,8) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.10,13.5) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
            };
            \addlegendentry{Var 2b}
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}\[b\]{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}\[
                width=\linewidth,
                height=0.6\linewidth,
                xlabel={\footnotesize $x$},
                ylabel={\footnotesize $y$},
                xmin=-0.0020, xmax=0.102,
                title style={at={(-0.13,1.15)}, anchor=north west},
                ymin=2, ymax=9,
                grid=major,
                title={\footnotesize b)},
                tick label style={font=\scriptsize},
                xtick={0,0.02,0.04,0.06,0.08,0.10},
                xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/precision=2},
            \]
            \addplot\[
                color=red,
                mark=*,
                solid,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            \]
            coordinates {
                (0.00,7.5) += (0,0.4) -= (0,0.2)
                (0.10,3.2) += (0,0.4) -= (0,0.2)
            };
            
            \addplot\[
                color=pink,
                mark=square*,
                densely dashed,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            \]
            coordinates {
                (0.00,7.5) += (0,1) -= (0,2)
                (0.10,7.5) += (0,1) -= (0,3)
            };
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}
    \centering
    \ref{commonlegend}
    \caption{Caption.}
\end{figure}
\lipsum\[3\]
\end{document}][1]][1]


The easiest solution is to use markers that are shaped such that they can't completely hide each other. For instance you could use Mercedes star and Mercedes star flipped, or also x or ...

Also, depending on the magnitude of your data and in which areas the graphs are very near to each other, a logarithmic scale might help as well.

In addition to different marker styles, you could also choose different line styles. If the covered line is solid and the line on top of it dashed in a different colour, one will be able to see both lines.

This here uses the strategy mentioned in my comment, namely use markers that are uniquely shaped and not large filled shapes. There might be better combinations of markers (consult the pgfplots manual on the available shapes), but the gist remains the same:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                width=\linewidth,
                height=0.6\linewidth,
                xlabel={\footnotesize $x$},
                ylabel={\footnotesize $y$},
                xmin=0, xmax=0.1,
                ymin=8, ymax=16,
                grid=major,
                title={\footnotesize a)},
                tick label style={font=\scriptsize},
                title style={at={(-0.15,1.15)}, anchor=north west},
                xtick={0,0.02,0.04,0.06,0.08,0.10},
                xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/precision=2},
                legend style={
                    font=\footnotesize,
                    legend columns=-1,
                    cells={anchor=west},
                    draw=black,
                },
                legend to name=commonlegend
            ]
            \addplot[
                color=red,
                mark=x,
                solid,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            ] 
            coordinates {
                (0.00,8) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.10,9.2) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
            };
            \addlegendentry{Var 1a}
            
            \addplot[
                color=red,
                mark=Mercedes star,
                densely dashed,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            ]
            coordinates {
                (0.00,8) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.10,10.5) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
            };
            \addlegendentry{Var 1b}
            
            \addplot[
                color=blue,
                mark=star,
                solid,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            ]
            coordinates {
                (0.00,8) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.10,9.2) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
            };
            \addlegendentry{Var 2a}
            
            \addplot[
                color=blue,
                mark=Mercedes star flipped,
                densely dashed,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            ]
            coordinates {
                (0.00,8) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.10,13.5) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
            };
            \addlegendentry{Var 2b}
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                width=\linewidth,
                height=0.6\linewidth,
                xlabel={\footnotesize $x$},
                ylabel={\footnotesize $y$},
                xmin=-0.0020, xmax=0.102,
                title style={at={(-0.13,1.15)}, anchor=north west},
                ymin=2, ymax=9,
                grid=major,
                title={\footnotesize b)},
                tick label style={font=\scriptsize},
                xtick={0,0.02,0.04,0.06,0.08,0.10},
                xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/precision=2},
            ]
            \addplot[
                color=red,
                mark=Mercedes star,
                solid,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            ]
            coordinates {
                (0.00,7.5) += (0,0.4) -= (0,0.2)
                (0.10,3.2) += (0,0.4) -= (0,0.2)
            };
            
            \addplot[
                color=pink,
                mark=Mercedes star flipped,
                densely dashed,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            ]
            coordinates {
                (0.00,7.5) += (0,1) -= (0,2)
                (0.10,7.5) += (0,1) -= (0,3)
            };
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}
    \centering
    \ref{commonlegend}
    \caption{Caption.}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}][1]][1]


As you can see, it's not perfect but at least a bit better.
